# Set up Java path for terminal

Tags: command-line, java

[image]

Trying to set up a path for the terminal. I already have Eclipse running great. Dual os between windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. However, I would prefer to run everything out of Ubuntu, just not very experienced and all the forums I have searched are not giving me the step by step answers I need to make this happen. I included a screen shot of some information about my version etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point I've put 10+ hours into this and this is my last resort.

Comment: You need to more clearly explain what it is you are trying to do.  It looks like both javac and java are in your path already. Is it the wrong version of java?

Comment: i think they mean the path to 'HelloWorld'.  Xsteen, try using `/path/to/the/file/to/run` in place of just "HelloWorld"

Comment: You don't need screenshots for textinterfaces on Linux. Mark the whole text with your mouse, and paste it by middle-click (=mouse-wheel) into the edit-field. Format it with the Code-tag (`<S>`). Ctrl+C and  Ctrl+V work too, but not  Ctrl+X for submitted commands, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Hi actually you are not following the syntax properly .

To Compile a java file you have to do

`javac filename.java`  and for your case that command will be `javac HelloWorld.java`

to Run a Java file  you have to do

`java filename` and for your case `java HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

```
javac HelloWorld
```

is wrong in that way, that java**c** is a call for the Java**c**ompiler, and you invoke it on a Java source file, which would be HelloWorld.java in your case.

Then you can't check the version of javac by looking for **java** or asking **java -version**. Do **javac -version**  and **which javac** instead.

To switch between different versions completely, you use

```
update-java-alternatives
```

To switch an individual program (javac but not java or vice versa, or jar or appletviewer and so on)

```
update-alternatives --set java
```

Without the alternatives system you would change the **PATH**, and insert /usr/lib/jvm/java-7/bin for example, or sort it  before java-1.6.